# firestore equality filter with orderBy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore and I have very simple queries with equality filter where I am required to do orderBy (because I have to limit the results). I can't use startAfter withour orderBy, because Firebase throws an error in that case.

> FirebaseError: Too many arguments provided to Query.startAfter(). The number of arguments must be less than or equal to the number of Query.orderBy() clauses

However, I can't use orderBy with an equality filter. Example:

```
query.where('tags.supporter', '==', true).orderBy('tags.supporter');
```

This throws a Firebase error:

> FirebaseError: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality
>   filter tags.supporter

Funny enough, this works just fine :-

```
query.where('tags.supporter', '<=', true).where('tags.supporter', '>=', true)
```

^ this works and gives me tags.supporter == true, but I can't use it with multiple filters.

Example:

```
query.where('tags.supporter', '==', true).where('tags.volunteer', '==', true)
```

^ works, but I can't use startAfter without orderBy. But if I try to use orderBy, I get the error :-

```
query.where('tags.supporter', '==', true).where('tags.volunteer', '==', true).orderBy(...)
```

^ doesn't work!

I can't do the <= >= hack because it requires composite index but I can't set that up because these are user-added tags.

Any ideas?

If this truly is a limitation then it should be mentioned explicitly in the documentation because it would have influenced my decision. Now I'll have to either build a lot of logic in my own app to filter results if this truly is a limitation.

Comment: What do you expect the first query to do?  Orderby is unnecessary in this case since it's already sorted by that single age value you requested.  If you want to limit the number of results, you should be able to limit() without orderBy().

Comment: It doesn't work because when I use startAfter later, I get this error :-

FirebaseError: Too many arguments provided to Query.startAfter(). The number of arguments must be less than or equal to the number of Query.orderBy() clauses

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than the one you started out with.  I suggest posting a new question to describe the new problem.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why it's required to order results that are already ordered.

Comment: That's a part of my question too.  Firestore will not allow me to use startAfter unless I explicitly call "orderBy".  And it won't let me do "orderBy" for an equality filter (because like you said, it's already ordered).  Since the documentation mentions nothing, i think it might be a bug.

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly how you're using startAfter that generates the error message.  It's best if the question goes into enough detail such that it's easy for anyone to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 9):

After a lot of trial and error, I figured it out.

You can use `.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())`. This allows you to use multiple equality filters and still do limit and startAfter.

Comment: It sounds like you maybe didn't try the version of startAfter that takes a document snapshot as opposed to field values.  Since you didn't show the actual code that uses startAfter, we don't really know what exactly was breaking in your question.

Comment: An example in TypeScript for Admin SDK: `import { FieldPath } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';`

`query.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId.toString(), "asc");`

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you are given a *array* of 10 elements ,having each of its item the value '5' . Now you have to sort the array (or to say , ***orderBy*** ascending ), how will you do so. Answer is its '*already sorted*'.

Same goes with your *Query* having first *filter* on *age* and then *orderBy* on that same property i.e age .
It works fine with range filter `age>=7` and`age<=7` because it includes the complete range of age and finally contain something to *orderBy*.

`query.where("age", "<=", 7).where("age", ">=", 7).orderBy("age)`

Filter with equality ( on *age* ) returns you a *queryset* of data having *same value* of the property on which you applied the filter, i.e each and every data object in your returned *queryset* is of uniform age ,there is no distinction on the basis of age (yes you can and should be applying *orderBy* on other properties for sure).

Comment: The reason I need orderBy is because I am limiting the result and using startAfter, since the query can literally result thousands of results.

I can't use startAfter without explicitly using orderBy.

Comment: Why not *orderby*  on some other property (other than age, because you already used the *is equal filter *).@zee

Comment: Because that requires a composite index and I can't set that because these are user-added fields.