# firestore query working in emulator but not production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My package.json

```
"firebase": "^9.6.6",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-firebase-hooks": "^5.0.2",
```

I  use the firebase query  inside a component like this

```
const CreatedEventsComponent = ({ user }: { user: User }) => {
    logScreenView('Created Events');
    const eventRef = collection(db, 'users', user.uid, 'events')
    const q = query(eventRef, where('deleted', "==", false), orderBy('deleted', "desc"), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'))
    const [events, loading] = useCollection(q);

    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />;
    }

    return (
        <Container size='lg'>
            <Space h='lg' />
            {
                events?.empty ? <Title order={4}>You have not created any events yet.</Title> : events?.docs.map(
                    (event, index) => <EventItem key={index} event={event} index={index} isOwn={true} />)
            }
        </Container>
    )
}
```

This query works perfectly fine in emulator mode, however on production it does not return any value

I have the following indexes on my firestore collection
[image: firebase.indexes]

Please note that events is under the users collection (it is a sub-collection)

Not able to understand why it is working in the emulator mode and not in the live site.
I am able to see that the eventRef variable is set properly.

Update on the issue:

changed component class

```
const CreatedEventsComponent = ({ user }: { user: User }) => {
    logScreenView('Created Events');
    const eventRef = collection(db, 'users', user.uid, 'events')
    const q = query(eventRef, where('deleted', "==", false), orderBy('deleted', "desc"), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'))
    const [events, loading, errors] = useCollection(q);

    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />;
    }
if(errors) {
console.log (errors)
}
    return (
        <Container size='lg'>
            <Space h='lg' />
            {
                events?.empty ? <Title order={4}>You have not created any events yet.</Title> : events?.docs.map(
                    (event, index) => <EventItem key={index} event={event} index={index} isOwn={true} />)
            }
        </Container>
    )
}
```

I get the following errors on console.

> FirebaseError: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter deleted

Since,  I have a 'deleted' field it cannot be used in combination with the orderby clause.
Also this field is a boolean field ( a flag set to indicate if the document was deleted or not)

I looked into this top StackOverflow question
[firestore equality filter with orderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830082/firestore-equality-filter-with-orderby)

and it says to use documentId as a orderby, however I do not want to order on documentId.

Comment: Your code does not appear to be checking for errors on the query.  Something could be going wrong and you'd never know.

Comment: ok, will use errors and check on that and will update this. thanks

Comment: @DougStevenson, I got this error, " FirebaseError: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter deleted" What would this mean? thanks again.

Comment: Please edit the question to show all your debugging information.  If you made changes to code, show that as well as your logs.

Comment: I removed the orderBy ('deleted', 'desc') clause and it is working now. However, earlier I had included that since firebase complained that, I need to have that field that was used in the equality operator or something similar. But right now it is working fine.
I will leave the question open if anybody has better suggestion. thanks @DougStevenson for help. I do not know why I did not use errors :(  earlier :D

Comment: If the emulator has reproducible, different behavior than the production cloud service, please file a bug on the emulator: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you, I have filled a bug as the same thing is happening to us https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4701